# UWP: 0x80131040: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I am trying to use a Windows Runtime Component in a C++/WinRT Console App.
The Component is written in C#, and I added it as a reference in the C++ project.

Everything compiles, but this error is thrown when I call a function of the component, and I can't catch it.

I already cleaned the project, and nothing changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only native UWP app to managed UWP component activation is supported. This means if you want to manage c# component from C++/WinRT, you need to create a C++ UWP app(e.g. C++/WinRT UWP app). In that case, you can call the c# component from C++/WinRT UWP app.